# the lived lives of people

Tags: expressions

There's one thing that caught my eye in a GRE sample essay. Below are the prompt of the essay and an excerpt taken from it.

Prompt:
"As people rely more and more on technology to solve problems, the ability of humans to think for themselves will surely deteriorate.

Discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the statement and explain your reasoning for the position you take. In developing and supporting your position, you should consider ways in which the statement might or might not hold true and explain how these considerations shape your position."

Here's the opening paragraph of the essay:
"The statement linking technology negatively with free thinking plays on recent human experience over the past century. Surely there has been no time in history where ***the lived lives of people*** have changed more dramatically."

The expression in bold struck me as odd, so I googled it up to see if anyone has ever used that before. But I found nothing. I could probably get the meaning of this expression based on the context, but I am not sure if it is idiomatic. Have you ever seen it or heard of it before?

Comment: [google "lived lives"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lived+lives%22). It's perfectly grammatical, semantically curious, stylistically questionable, pleonastically repetitive. It's not an idiom but has been used before. It's sort of an emphasis about peoples individual lives and how they are lived in actuality. It sounds like it's trying to be clever, but comes across as unimaginative.

Comment: googling "the lived lives" brings up thousands of hits. The majority that I skimmed on the first 10 pages of hits have a usage identical to your quote. Well-attested in google books as well

Comment: 'Slept sleeps' is far more dubious, though 'he slept the sleep of the dead' is as idiomatic as 'she lived a life of ease'. Look up 'cognate objects'.

Comment: There's a philosophical notion of _lived experience_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lived_experience).

Comment: Yes, "lived experience" is a popular buzzword at the moment.  However "lived lives" just sounds pompous, pretentious and stupid to me. Ignore it and, with luck, it will go away.